# Change color of shape with mouse hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xcode

```
<html>

    <head>

        <title>Interactive Playground</title>

        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                position:relative;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .box1{
                height: 100%;
                width:100%;
                position:absolute;
                background-color: palevioletred;
            }

            .box2{
                height: 85%;
                width:90%;
                background-color: lightpink;
                display:block;
                position:absolute;
            }

            .box3{
                height: 65%;
                width:80%;
                background-color: pink;
                display:block;
                position:absolute;
            }

            .box4{
                height: 45%;
                width:70%;
                background-color: navajowhite;
                display:block;
                position:absolute;
            }

            .box5{
                height: 30%;
                width:60%;
                background-color: goldenrod;
                display:block;
                position:absolute;
            }

            .box6{
                height: 15%;
                width:50%;
                background-color: darkgoldenrod;
                display:block;
                position:absolute;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

         <div id="box" class="box1"></div>
         <div id="box" class="box2"></div>
         <div id="box" class="box3"></div>
         <div id="box" class="box4"></div>
         <div id="box" class="box5"></div>
         <div id="box" class="box6"></div>

         <script>

         </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**I want to make each individual box change to a separate color with a mouse hover. How would I write that syntax with jquery?** I am trying to eventually create where a mouse hover will create separate gradients that move while the mouse is on each box. This is to create an interactive experience, please help!

Comment: You could also use CSS `:hover` instead of JS for a simple colour change on hover.

Comment: **My main goal is to have a background gradient on each box when mouse enters with jquery** to clear up any confusion!

Comment: And what have you tried so far..? I can't see any JS/Jquery code here.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri I do not know how to get started with Jquery. I have removed the times I have tried with both id's and classes on each of the boxes because It was not responding to anything but I do not think I was starting the syntax right. I am looking for just a start to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use **[jQuery](https://jquery.com/)**. Instead, you should use **[`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)**. You should also read about  **[CSS pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)**. In your sample code, you can accomplish this like so:

```
.box1 {
   height: 100%;
   width:100%;
   position:absolute;
   background-color: palevioletred;
}

.box1:hover{
   background-color: blue;
}

.box2 {
     height: 85%;
     width:90%;
     background-color: lightpink;
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
}

.box2:hover {
   background-color: green;
}
```

If you still want to use **jQuery** for whatever reason, there are many ways to accomplish this. You could try it like this:

```
$('.box1').mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).css('background', 'green');
});

$('.box1').mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).css('background', 'palevioletred');
});
```

You can check this **[working code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/dg7f0ch2/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the hover states:

```
.box1 {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: palevioletred;
}

.box1:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.box2 {
    height: 85%;
    width:90%;
    background-color: lightpink;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;

}

.box2:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Just add hover states to your selectors with the color you want to use.

I made .box1 & .box2 as examples. Hope it helps !

#### EDIT:

As per the comments, OP wants this to be done via jQuery (go figure out why), here is a solution with jQuery:

```
$( ".box1" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

Example above is for .box1, you need to do the rest.

You need to add this code snippet inside a script and once your DOM is loaded.

But this is really not recommended way of doing things!!

Comment: I cannot use hover, it has to be done with jquery. But that does work, I just need it done in a different way. Thank you though!

Comment: Why you need this to be done via jquery? It is not the right tool for the job! This is a pure CSS problem.

Comment: This is an assignment, I just need help getting started with how to use jquery. I have not used that syntax before and I don't know how to lay it out for this particular project.

Comment: @DaniellePritchett there you go! I updated my answer.

Comment: @avcajaraville thank you so much, put when I put that code into the script and remove the box 1 hover from the css scripting it is not responding. Do you know why?

Comment: Have you linked the Jquery library?

Comment: @RajanBenipuri that fixed it! can't believe I forgot that part. It works great now.

Comment: @DaniellePritchet how come my answer is not the accepted one?

Comment: @avcajaraville I liked both answers and am not sure how to do that :( I am new to this website so am honestly not quite sure how things work